# How to display two values from json_encode array on the same line using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jquery .autocomplete() for a html search form that gets data from json_encode array.
The fetched array has two values when it's a match - company_code and company_name.

The .autocomplete() displays values one under the other, but I want them on the same line.

This is my code to get the array, and it gets the two values:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT TICKER, COMPANY_NAME FROM companies WHERE TICKER LIKE :term OR COMPANY_NAME LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => $_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] =  $row['TICKER'];
        $return_arr[] =  $row['COMPANY_NAME'];            
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The jquery autocomplete script is this one:

```
$(function() {
$(".search").autocomplete({
    source: "/php/autocomplete.php",
    minLength: 1
});
```

The output comes out as:
[drop down menu with two items one under the other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUFNY.png)

Comment: It might help to include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Thanks, showdev. Don't know why I thought it was originally clear enough - it's late.

Comment: It looks like maybe because those two values are each added to the return array, so they are treated as two different results. What if you combine them into the same entry, e.g. `$return_arr[] =  $row['TICKER'] . ' - ' . $row['COMPANY_NAME'];` Is that what you're aiming for?

Comment: Thank you, showdev. It is exactly what I was aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fairly simple, you can just concatenate the column values together as a single array element instead of separate elements.

For example, instead of this:

```
$return_arr[] =  $row['TICKER'];
$return_arr[] =  $row['COMPANY_NAME'];
```

Do this:

```
$return_arr[] = $row['TICKER'] . ' ' . $row['COMPANY_NAME'];
```

Notice I am concatenating the two column values as one string (with a space in the middle).

The reason why your code doesn't work is that when you do `$return_arr[] =  'some_value'`, you are appending a new element to the json array, and jQuery UI Autocomplete sees each element as a separate list item.

Comment: Thank you, Kodos. I still lack the intuitive knowledge about what I can do with php so I get stuck with little things like this. Now I'm off trying to figure out how to format the dropdown menu with more than just the space in between.

Comment: @Ante just replace the `' '` with your desired separator. For example, `' | '` or `' - '` or anything else. Just make sure it is enclosed in quote marks.

Comment: is there a way to add more than one whitespace in this case? For my situation, the output should look something like: "code [multiple whitespaces] name". If the array value is "code name" I can't figure out how to style it on the other end.

Comment: @Ante Have you tried just putting multiple spaces, like `'        '`. If that doesn't work, it probably rendering the output as HTML which by default collapses multiple spaces to one space. You could also try `'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'`.

Comment: I tried both, it comes out as a single whitespace or it just prints out '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' instead of the whitespace.

Comment: @Ante I think I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563371/jquery-autocomplete-not-showing-2-or-multiple-spaces-in-drop-down-suggested. So you will have to override the `_renderItem` function to add the `style='white-space: pre-wrap'` style.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Kodos. That worked just as I need it. Next time I'll make sure to look for prior answers to similar questions to mine more diligently. Have a good one.